# Ubuntu 18.04 bios firmware update for my lenovo thinkpad P50 Crashed

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, thinkpad, bios

Got a message for a critical firmware update for my P50 ..clicked update and restarted. Now when i power-on the led for the power button lights up plus the backlit keyboard...blank screen not even the lenovo logo comes on and stays like that.

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Can you try to manually update your BIOS via USB??

Comment: I have tried but the screen is just blank does not even reach the POST stage where it tries to boot anything...no lenovo logo nothing. once you power on the screen goes blank.

Comment: OK.. Can you go through the manual and see which key will take you to BIOS Screen? I suspect system is trying to boot to HDD/ SSD and thus black screen due to some corruption.